# "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page" on Admin login page. I set the wrong cookie domain in the Admin panel. How to change that in the database?

Tags: error, cookie, admin-login

```
Magento 1.9.4
```

I am setting up a new Magento 1.9.4 store but I am setting that up for an existing live store which is currently running Magento 1.9.1.

I made the mistake of entering the other domain into the cookie domain setting in the Admin panel and it won't let me login into the Admin panel. I get the following  Error:

```
Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.
```

I deleted browser and Magento Cache (via FTP) and tried a different browser. I get the same Error. I need to find the table in the database to change the cookie domain there but I am not sure where to look? I am in phpMyAdmin.

*I found core_config_data but I don't see it there.*

Comment: Search records for path `web/cookie/cookie_domain`

Answer (score 0):

I found the web/cookie/cookie_domain row and corrected the domain. Deleted the Cache folder afterwords and it works now.